# XRDP multiple log in sessions

Tags: linux

I use xrdp, and I am trying to have multiple sessions with the same user (ABC).

I do not have any connection issues.  What's happening is when I open the second session it just mirrors whats happening in the first screen, but when I change the screen resolutions on both the screens, it does not do it — but it's not possible to change resolutions all the time.

Answer (score 0):

This is answered here:
https://github.com/neutrinolabs/xrdp/issues/907

Change the Policy in /etc/xrdp/sesman.ini